# NYC subway GTFS file is unreadable

Tags: general-transit-feed-specification

I've been wanting to make a transit appliance for my husband that shows the next train for a long time, but GTFS has always stopped me. I already got it working for NYC buses and metro north. [image]

In the case of the bus and metro north there was a JSON file or and XML file that I could parse for the next two buses or trains for a given stop id.

But the subway uses GTFS. And even after getting a developers key and reading the documentation:

http://datamine.mta.info/sites/all/files/pdfs/GTFS-Realtime-NYC-Subway%20version%201%20dated%207%20Sep.pdf

The data look like this:

```
"
 1.0´‹“€ >

 1.0
 G≥Í“€∞

 36000001£

 2

 109550_G..N20180815*G >
 1G 1815 CHU/CRS#õ‹“€õ‹“€"G26N( >
 E2#±›“€±›“€"G24N( >
E2E2#Ì›“€Ì›“€"G22N( >
 D2D2J
 36000002">
2
109550_G..N20180815*G >
```

So seeing this I get that it's not text. I'm programing an esp8266, a tiny microprocessor. How can I parse this? I looked in to creating a webpage on my server (where I have PHP) to do the parsing, google says GTFS works with PHP but all of the applications I've found require installing a whole lot of stuff on my server. Or they use python which isn't available on my server.

I feel like I must be missing something. What is the simplest way to do this?

If the MTA's "train time" site was more text based I'd just scrape it. I'm that frustrated.

I found some of the GTFS threads here helpful hope some of the wise folk can help.

Comment: Hi, I think this might be suited to another SE Site, not the GIS SE. Doing a search of the main Stack Overflow Site I found a few GTFS based questions. https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=gtfs Perhaps you might have better luck there.

Comment: I've tried posting at the coding stackexchange and they didn't like this question much. Made more progress in the GTFS google group.

Comment: Here is the thread from the google group

https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/gtfs-realtime/_1dE8Vx9SjI/f3dNNXFbCQAJ